# logstash to pickup data from multiple lines

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am trying to write logstash filter to extract some data from multiple log lines.

I thought to make use of `multiline` filter, but that doesn't seem to solve my problem:

If I merge lines based on some common pattern, say `0x000005fa` in this case, there are 100 other lines which starts with the pattern `0x000005fa`.

I have log lines like following.

```
< p:0x000005fa P:STM t:0x00ba94f0 T:component M:file1.c F:func_1 L:2343 > module Helper library has reported: check on partition /dev/point1 failed errno=13
< p:0x000005fa P:STM t:0x00ba94f0 T:component M:file2.c F:func_2 L:1899 > %%%%Erasing HDD%%%%
< p:0x000005fa P:STM t:0x00ba94f0 T:component M:file3.c F:func_3 L:1433 > ...partition /dev/point1 format complete
```

I finally want my output to have following data:

```
mount_point:/dev/point1
error_code:13
format_string: Erasing HDD
format_status: complete
```

I tried following, I.e. have a python script which might do some combination of grep, sed and awk to fetch the required data and set that data as a new event called process_result, then later we can use grok to fetch exact data. But I think combination of these commands can slow down my logstash if run on huge set of data?

```
ruby {
code => 'require "open3"
         file_path = event.get("C:\Users\sushiku2\Downloads\ELK\logstash-5.4.0\Logs\diag-logs\hdd-failure\DIAG_Sample_12345_00")
         #cmd =  "my_filter.py -f #{file_path}"
         cmd = "python my_filter.py"
         stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3(cmd)
         event.set("process_result", stdout.read)
         err = stderr.read
         if err.to_s.empty?
           filter_matched(event)
         else
           event.set("ext_script_err_msg", err)
         end'
  remove_field => ["file_path"]
}
```